# Abstract Factory Pattern in Java

Tags: java, abstract-factory

I reproduced my version of Abstract Factory Pattern in Java. I know it's redundant but can I get critical comments about my code. Is it really the classic implementation of the pattern or not?

```
/*
* The demonstration of Abstract Factory Pattern
* 
* Here the 'DocumentFactory' creates documents of types 
* 'Resume' or 'Letter' which are concrete classes responsible to
* create things like 'FancyResume' or 'CoverLetter'
* 
* The example is inspired by Wikipedia documentation of Abstract
* Factory.
*/

interface letter{
    void print();
}

class CoverLetter implements letter{
    @Override
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Cover letter printed");
    }
}

class FancyLetter implements letter{
    @Override
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Fancy letter printed");
    }
}

interface resume{
    void process();
}

class CorporateResume implements resume{
    @Override
    public void process(){
        System.out.println("Corporate resume processed");
    }
}

class FancyResume implements resume{
    @Override
    public void process(){
        System.out.println("Fancy resume processed");
    }
}

//Create 'Concrete' factories 
class LetterFactory{
    public letter getLetter(String type){
        switch(type){
            case "Fancy":
                return new FancyLetter();
            case "Cover":
                return new CoverLetter();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class ResumeFactory{
    public resume getResume(String type){
        switch(type){
            case "Fancy":
                return new FancyResume();
            case "Corporate":
                return new CorporateResume();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

// create abstract factory
abstract class DocumentFactory{
    abstract LetterFactory letterFactory();
    abstract ResumeFactory resumeFactory();
}

class DocumentCreator extends DocumentFactory{
    @Override
    LetterFactory letterFactory(){
        return new LetterFactory();
    }

    @Override
    ResumeFactory resumeFactory(){
        return new ResumeFactory();
    }
}

class abstractfactory{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        DocumentCreator creator = new DocumentCreator();

        // create a fancy letter
        letter myLetter = creator.letterFactory().getLetter("Fancy");
        myLetter.print();

        // create a corporate resume
        resume myResume = creator.resumeFactory().getResume("Corporate");
        myResume.process();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you would benefit from this extra level of abstraction here. And I find it very confusing that some of your types have lower-case names.

Comment: Is this not a valid implementation of "Abstract Factory" pattern?

Comment: I think you might have been trapped by one of the more dangerous aspects of design patterns: When followed blindly, they encourage cargo-cult programming for the sake of using the pattern rather than actually trying to solve a problem. If we should review your code, we have to know what it's supposed to accomplish. Also note that [we don't review hypothetical code here](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3652/67456).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use standard Java conventions for interfaces names: not `resume` or `letter` but `Letter` and `Resume`

Second, I would define e.g. `StyleDocumentsFactory` API like this

```
interface StyleDocumentsFactory {
    Letter createLetter();
    Resume createResume();
}
```

and then implement `FuncyStyleDocumentsFactory` and `CorporateStyleDocumentsFactory` instances of this API.

So you will have 2 [abstract factories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) (for creation group of object with *common theme*: `funcy` and `corporate`) with set of [factory methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Instantiate appropriate `StyleDocumentsFactory` impl in your `main` method at the program beginning.